# Evaluation of a complex integral

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $f(z)$ be an entire function with $f(0) = 1$. If $f$ has one zero $z = z_1$ in $|z| < R$, I want to prove that
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \log \left| f(Re^{i\theta}) \right| d\theta = \log \frac{R}{|z_1|}.
\end{equation*}
This is one of the intermediate steps in the proof of Jensen's theorem.

I was trying to prove this by recasting the left-hand side as
\begin{equation*}
\frac{1}{2\pi} \left( \int_0^{2\pi} \log \left| f(Re^{i\theta}) \right| d\theta \right) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{|z| = R} \frac{\log |f(z)|}{z} dz = \text{Res}\left(\frac{\log |f(z)|}{z},z_1 \right).
\end{equation*}

Is this recasting valid and if so, how should I calculate this residue? If not, how do I prove the above result anyway?

Edit: It was pointed out in the comments that the recasting does not make sense. Regardless, how do you prove the original result?

Comment: There is no analytic branch of $\log f(z)$ in general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I edited the post slightly. Forgot the modulus sign.

Comment: Residue is defined only when you have a Laurent series expansion . For $\log |f(z)|$ there is no Laurent series.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy  Ah okay, thanks! Do you know how to prove the original result?

Comment: Take $g(z)=f(z)\frac{R^2-z\bar z_1}{R(z_1-z)}$ and being non-zero in $|z| \le R$, it has a holomorphic logarithm, so $\log |g|=\Re \log g$ is harmonic and satisfies the mean value theorem - applying it to $z=0$ and evaluating both sides gives you the result

Comment: @Conrad Thanks!

Comment: happy to be of help